# Proper way to declare variable with uint8_t

Tags: c, initialization, definition, uint8t

I am programming MicroChip's MCU using C, but when I initialize a variable with `uint8_t` by using these methods:

```
(uint8_t) distance = 0;

((uint8_t) distance = 0);
```

And these methods too (declaration):

```
(uint8_t) distance;

((uint8_t) distance);
```

But this is what I received after compilation:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'distance'
```

BTW, I'm a novice at C programming.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do not try learning C by trial&error. This known to cause depressions. Read a book.

Comment: Please include a complete program, as small as possible, that shows the issue.

Comment: This type of error is probably derives from forgetting to include the header file that contains the identifier (name of a function, variable, class, etc) declaration.

Why is the parenthesis : ((uint8_t) distance = 0); ??

Comment: There is no "include missing", you're just using *wrong syntax*, i.e. a cast expression without side-effects. You cannot put the *type* in parentheses when writing a declaration, but you can parenthesize the *identifier*, i.e. `uint8_t ((((((((((((((distance))))))))))))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`stdint.h`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20) should define [`uint8_t`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.1).

So your .c-file needs to include the above mentioned .h-file before defining a variable of type `uint8_t`.

This could look like this:

```
#include <stdint.h> 

int main(void)
{
  uint8_t distance_uninitialised; /* Holds an indeterminated value. */
  uint8_t distance_initialised = 0;
}
```

Comment: That's worked! Thanks.